# Wilcoxon signed rank with multiple repetition

Tags: statistical-significance, wilcoxon-signed-rank

How could I do Wilcoxon signed-rank statistical significance test with multiple replications in python or other languages? (since python does not have any parameter as the input of the function for the number of repetitions)

about my problem:
I have some results from method1 and method2, I am gonna do a statistical test to show whether or not the results of the 1st method are significantly better than the 2nd one.

Comment: What formal hypothesis do you want to test?

Comment: I have some results from method1 and method2, I am gonna do a statistical test to show whether or not the results of the 1st method are significantly better than the 2nd one.

Comment: It's best to formulate the question very specifically.  And instead of asking if one method is "significantly" better than another, a better goal is probably to quantify how much better.   You can't judge method1 vs. method2 without having a gold standard or an outcome being predicted.  You can always just estimate the distribution of |method1 - method2|.

Comment: well in my case I got the results from 2 neural networks and calculated a measure, for example, ''mean square error'' for each output. now I have two vectors from the 1st network and the 2nd network. I suppose that the 1st network works better. I am gonna do a significant test to check whether or not it significantly works better. I am gonna do it with multiple replications. now please let me know what should I do?